# Split S3 files line by line and put in other bucket

Tags: amazon-data-pipeline

I have moderately sized files in S3 (which i got from the EMR) and each line has a key and object which i would like to put in separate bucket.

Is there anyway to implement this using data pipeline?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to copy this data into another s3 bucket, you can use CopyActivity in datapipeline to do this. Your pipeline will have a S3DataNode as an input to CopyActivity and an output S3DataNode.  You can get started by trying out one of the templates available in AWS datapipeline console and edit your pipeline to have the objects I have mentioned above.

Comment: I do not want to just copy the files , but i want to split the files line by line and put them in a separate bucket. for e,g: if i have 1000 lines in first file , will put them as 1000 items in separate bucket.